# GET XML via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

We are currently in the process of trying to get XML data in our marketing cloud emails. One of the solutions i am working on is trying to get the XML via amp script then populate the information via BuildRowsetFromXML

Currently in our CMS the XMLs headers are in the following format:

Example 1:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TourInfo
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BrandCode="IV" CMSId="IV_WEB" CMSTourId="24242756-5b37-4355-a59d-811feb66050b" Duration="18" TourCode="E396B14"
    xmlns="http://www.ttc.com/ch2/api/ccapi/v3/TourInfo/2014/01/3.0">
```

Example 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TourInfo
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BrandCode="IV" CMSId="IV_WEB" CMSTourId="6557978e-a6fa-449f-957d-4fda41f8ee8b" Duration="5" TourCode="B995B14"
    xmlns="http://www.ttc.com/ch2/api/ccapi/v3/TourInfo/2014/01/3.0">
```

In both of these examples I will be referencing the Tour Code which will be referenced from the Sendable Data Extension so any pulling that I do needs to be dynamic.

How could i accomplish this?

Giulietta